# How to turn off Preserve JavaScript console perseverance in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, settings

Currently in my Google Chrome JS console, all of my `console.log`s, network errors, etc. are preserved between page refreshes **even though I have `Preserve logs` disabled**. Does anyone know a fix to this? Here are my current settings for my console:

[image: javascript console settings screenshot]

Comment: That should be the reason for it, and I can't reproduce the problem with various other caching methods. Have you tried checking `Preserve log` and unchecking it, and possibly restarting Chrome?

Comment: Yeah @ObsidianAge, I've actually had this issue for a super long time. I've tried toggling this option here as well as toggling it in the full console settings from the dots in the upper right next to the x button-- nothing seems to disable this behavior!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue has been fixed for me by doing the following:

1. While inspect is open press F1.
2. Scroll to bottom and click
   ['Restore defaults and reload'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zboFq.png).
3. Close Google Chrome.
4. Reopen.

Also, you may need to delete Google Chrome and reinstall.

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks man! I didn't know there was a "Reset" button. Still have no idea why this worked, but ‍♂️

Comment: Yeah sorry, my comment was ambiguous. Just resetting my settings to default worked for me as well!